# Force linking library in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, aix, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Is there a way to get the build to force link to a specific library in a specific path in Linux/Aix? Is there a way to get the build to fail if the library is not in the specific path?

Providing the path this way:

```
-L/path/to/lib -lssl
```

does not seem to force the build to pick the library in that specific path.

This is to figure out how to handle these scenarios:

1. For cases where similarly named dynamic libraries exist in multiple paths where those paths are in LIBPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the build picks one of the other libraries based on the order of the paths in LIBPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
2. Where there are similarly named static libraries and dynamic libraries, the build seems to pick the static library over the dynamic one. I would like the build to fail if a static library exists but not the dynamic library, or pick the dynamic library if both exist.

Comment: Is scenario 1 what your linker *does*, or what *you want it to do?* Also, what linker are you using, gcc?

Comment: @Beta Scenarios 1 and 2 are what it does now. For 1, i'd like to know if there is a way to force link to the one in the path mentioned with the -L option. For 2, i'd like to know if there is a way to force dynamic linking for just one library over static linking, or just force link to the one in the path mention with the -L option. I just mentioned the two separately since the solutions might be different for each.

Comment: If you want to _link_ from a known location, change`-L/path/to/lib -lssl` to `/path/to/lib/libssl.so` On AIX, you can use linker-option `-bipath` to store the path of the library into the executable. Note: You might want to read this: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html

Comment: My guess is your question is not really your question.  If you have a specific platform you can create a call to ld that does exactly what you want it do.  What I *think* you are asking is how to do it in a generic sense so that it will always pick what I want on any system.  The answer to that is probably "no".  But you can create a (shell) script to do the searches and find the libraries that meet your criteria and create the precisely specified ld command.

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy: Thanks. That was what i was looking for.

Comment: @pedz: I am a bit new to makefiles. So my question was just a simple one. But your answer was informative. Thanks!

Comment: I am still curious to know if there is a way to specify that the library should only be linked dynamically. If for some reason, the library in the path specified is switched out with a static lib, the build should fail. (This question is specifically for aix where both dynamic and static libs are archives.)

Comment: Use option `-Wl,-brtl` to avoid this. One reason of many: you cannot have symlinks to archive-members.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind posting these comments as answers? I can mark them as the right answer.

Comment: Adding more info. It looks like using the bstatic option forces static linking with shared libraries. This would be something to lookout for in the makefiles. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.aix.doc/compiler_ref/bdynam.html#bdynam